# Dimension of minimal sufficient statistic

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, sufficient-statistics

Is this true that "dimension of every minimal sufficient statistic is less than any sufficient statistic (minimal or not)"?

Comment: if by "less" you mean "less than or equal to" this is correct since _a minimal sufficient statistic is a function of any sufficient statistic_.

Comment: @Xi'an: This looks like n answer, could you make it one?  https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5402/is-a-quick-and-dirty-answer-better-than-no-answer/5411#5411

Answer (score 1):

Since a *minimal sufficient statistic*$$T:\mathcal X\longmapsto \mathbb R^p$$is (i) *sufficient* and (ii) a *function of every sufficient statistic*$$S:\mathcal X\longmapsto \mathbb R^q$$that is, there exists $$t:\mathbb R^p\longmapsto \mathbb R^q$$ such that$$T(x)=t(S(x))$$it is necessary that$$p\le q$$Otherwise, if $p>q$, since $T(X)$ belongs to the $q$-dimensional manifold$$t(\mathbb R^q) = \{\tau;~\tau=t(s),\ s\in\mathbb R^q\}\subset\mathbb R^p$$there exists a reparameterisation of $T$ of dimension $q$.